# Fetching valid products from itunes connect for in app purchase in iOS takes a lot of time. How do I deal with it?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

There are some 800 plus products configured on the iTunes connect. When I initially send all the product identifiers to Apple while app launch to validate them, it takes almost 20 seconds to for the SKProduct request to return with the valid products.

Is there a way to optimise it?

I use the code from [Introduction to In-App Purchases in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Comment: Are you fetch all products from your own server or Add all products on Apple server?

Comment: try to call - (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers; within background thread instead of main thread

Answer (score 1):

Apple describe here how to manage large numbers of product identifier download / upload

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html